# SQLite: Unique per title and date (only date without time)

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, unique-constraint, generated-columns

I have a table in which i store some titles as a TEXT and a date also as a TEXT.

I am inserting the date value as a string in ISO format in the database.

Now i want to have a unique combination of title and date but only considering the date part(year, month and day) of the ISO string and ignoring the time part. So i want a unique title per specific day in the year.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (TITLE, DATE) VALUES ('TITLE_A', '2022-06-20T13:53:41.680Z') -- OK
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (TITLE, DATE) VALUES ('TITLE_A', '2022-06-20T22:12:32.430Z') -- NOT OK same title and only time is different
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (TITLE, DATE) VALUES ('TITLE_B', '2022-06-20T13:53:41.680Z') -- OK same date but title is different
```

What are my best options? I could implement a check but i'm not sure if that is the best option because as the table grows this could make the check slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not allow the use of functions inside the definition of a `UNIQUE` constraint, which would solve the problem like this:

```
UNIQUE(TITLE, date(DATE)) -- not allowed
```

Instead you can define a [generated column](https://www.sqlite.org/gencol.html) (version 3.31.0+) as the date part of the column `DATE` and use that in the definition of the constraint.

It would make more sense to rename your existing column to `TIMESTAMP` and name the generated column as `DATE`:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A (
  TITLE TEXT, 
  TIMESTAMP TEXT,
  DATE TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (date(TIMESTAMP)),
  UNIQUE(TITLE, DATE)
);

INSERT INTO TABLE_A (TITLE, TIMESTAMP) VALUES ('TITLE_A', '2022-06-20T13:53:41.680Z'); -- OK
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (TITLE, TIMESTAMP) VALUES ('TITLE_A', '2022-06-20T22:12:32.430Z'); -- error
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (TITLE, TIMESTAMP) VALUES ('TITLE_B', '2022-06-20T13:53:41.680Z'); -- OK
```

As it is, the generated column `DATE` is not actually stored in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain a pure date column and then impose a unique constraint on the combination of title and date.

```sql
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A (
    TITLE VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    DATE VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    TIMESTAMP VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT c_unique UNIQUE (TITLE, DATE)
);

INSERT INTO TABLE_A (TITLE, DATE, TIMESTAMP)
VALUES ('TITLE_A', '2022-06-20', '2022-06-20T13:53:41.680Z') -- passes
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (TITLE, DATE, TIMESTAMP)
VALUES ('TITLE_A', '2022-06-20', '2022-06-20T22:12:32.430Z') -- fails
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (TITLE, DATE, TIMESTAMP)
VALUES ('TITLE_B', '2022-06-20', '2022-06-20T13:53:41.680Z') -- passes
```

Comment: Can the constraint be c_unique UNIQUE (TITLE, CAST TIMESTAMP AS DATE)?

Comment: actually it would need to be CHECK NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_A WHERE ...)

Comment: @Hogan If your first comment be valid syntax, then it can be used over my answer.

Comment: Yeah... looking at https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/table-constraint.html it does not look like it would work and I don't have sqlite installed to check

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer. The only problem i see with this is that SQLite doesn't have TIMESTAMP and DATE data types. So that would mean i could also just manipulate the insert on the backend side and insert values with YYYY-MM-DD format. But i wanted actually to avoid this

Comment: @user3320813 SQLite may have a date _affinity_, but no, there is no actual date type.  Rather, dates are just stored as text.